# Call local Python script from PHP hosted on server

Tags: php, python, apache

I have PHP code on Apache server and PHP script just to call python script. This solution works fine if Python script is on same machine where is PHP script. But now I moved php on server and I am trying to call python script on another PC. Can someone please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a curl call to python script on other server.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://192.168.2.100/script.py");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Code taken from: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php